# How can you suppress SyntaxWarning in Python?

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

How can you suppress SyntaxWarning in Python ?

Here's the line of code that generates the warning.

```
def myfunction():
    from myimportfile import *
```

Please Note:

> 1. Importing the file outside the function is not an option. The import works. It just throws a SyntaxWarning anyhow.
> 2. **warnings.simplefilter('ignore')** will not work since the warning is generated before the code is actually run

For instance,

```
 def myfunction():
    print 'trace 1'
    from myimportfile import *
    print 'trace 2'
```

Will output

```
SyntaxWarning  
trace1  
trace2
```

and not

```
trace1  
SyntaxWarning  
trace2
```

So, how do I disable the warning?
And is it possible to disable the warning for this specific line of code alone?

Comment: What is your python version?
Also, it's not the best idea to import this way. You're better off importing at the top of your code file

Comment: That warning is there because, exactly as it says, "import * only allowed at module level". It's an error in later versions of Python. It also probably drastically enlarges the locals of your function, which is a bad thing to do. Why can't you just `from myimportfile import a, b`, or `import myimportfile` and use the qualified names, or move the import to module level?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not just a bad idea, it's illegal. As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) says:

> The `from` form with `*` may only occur in a module scope. If the wild card form of import — `import *` — is used in a function and the function contains or is a nested block with free variables, the compiler will raise a SyntaxError.

During transitional versions (off the top of my head, in this case I think that's 2.6, 2.7, and 3.0, but don't quote me on that) that error might be a warning instead. But if you upgrade to a later version, or possibly just use a different implementation of the same version, you will get an actual error instead. (For later versions: you definitely get an error in CPython 3.3. For different implementations of the same version: I tested with a PyPy 1.9.0 beta and PyPy 1.9.0 final, which both implement Python 2.7; the beta prints out 3 warnings and then raises an exception, the final spews 3 warnings scattered horizontally across the screen, then prints 3 more normal warnings.)

If at all possible, you should do one (or more) of the following:

- Move the import to module level.
- `from myimportfile import foo, bar` instead of `*`.
- `import myimportfile` and then use everything by qualified names.

If you absolutely must import everything in `myimportfile` into your function's `locals` scope, you're better off coming up with a hacky way to do that which isn't illegal, instead of a hacky way to work around the warning. For example:

```
import myimportfile
locals().update(myimportfile.__dict__)
```

This trivial version doesn't have exactly the same effect, but you can get as close as you want. For example, to do the usual limiting, filter on `name in myimportfile.__all__` if present, or `not name.startswith('_') or name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__')`. Or, if you're using 3.1 or later, use `importlib` instead of doing it manually.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the question. The question was not about fixing the code, the question was about suppressing the warnings. This is especially important, because the warnings that may be harmless (or even beneficial) during the development stage, become a huge pain for end-uses, especially if program output is parsed algorithmically.

Comment: There's nothing "illegal" about it. There are practical cases, where this makes sense. Maybe OP's example is not the best but imagine having a test to ensure that everything from a module can be imported.